# Textarea has wrong scrollHeight because of CSS height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I have the following example in codepen: https://codepen.io/cheryllium/pen/wvYmmxW

I want the textarea to grow to the minimum content height plus a little vertical padding, hence I have:

```
     function resizeTextarea() {
         const textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
         console.log(textarea.scrollHeight);
         textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 100 + 'px';
     }
```

However, the `scrollHeight` appears to grow by 100px every time a character is pressed, instead of actually being equal to the minimum height of the content. It's growing by the 100px I added to the height, for some reason.

In codepen, you can open the console to see the `scrollHeight` value printed.

Why is it doing this and how can I make it grow the way I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every time there is input, the function gets the scrollHeight (including the 100px padding you added) and adds another 100px + scrollHeight to the current height of the text area,

simple solution, reset the height of the textarea to "auto" before you recalculate the new height.

```
function resizeTextarea() {
     const textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
     console.log(textarea.scrollHeight);

     textarea.style.height = "auto" //reset height to auto

     textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 100 + 'px';
 }
```